# Given new closing nomenclature, how do I close a contest problem?

Tags: support, closing, close-reasons, contests

What should I use to request that a problem be closed as it has been posed by Brilliant? In the past, I tended to use "not constructive / too localized". Currently, none of "duplicate,   off-topic, unclear what you're asking, too broad, primarily opinion-based" seem to apply.

I just came across the following [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425905/reducible-four-degree-polynomial), posed by a user who has also posed Brilliant problems in the past. I've flagged it, and tried to close it, but none of the tags seems relevant.

I'm fine if the conclusion is simply to flag it, but this seems to give moderators too much power, instead of getting the community to decide to close it (and reopen it later if they wish).

Answer (score 10):

Despite the new closing system, [I am still feeling](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9896/622) that a moderator lockdown+notice or temporary deletion is a much better solution (it also prevents fights in the comments, or answers in the comments).

Comment: To add to that, a moderator's action takes effect immediately (as opposed to going through the review queue), and in these situations the timeliness of a response is very important. But you can cast an "off topic" vote with the custom reason "Questions from open contests are not on-topic on Mathematics.SE" or something like that, if you want to use both ways.

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if your suggested meta thread ever exists, which would make it easier to track such locked questions (and reopen them in a timely fashion).

Comment: @Calvin: Of course. The moderators have tested some things on that thread, but there was no final word on this. Perhaps this thread will nudge them a bit to take further action.

Comment: I agree: the most appropriate way to deal with this situation is by flagging the question.

Comment: @Alexander: Does that mean that the moderators have [generally] accepted the proposal about the semi-locked thread?